# Richfaces collapsiblePanel randomly causes javascript error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm working on a complex web application with RichFaces 4.5.13.Final and JSF 2.1 on JBoss EAP 6.4. Some pages containing a collapsiblePanel like this

```
            <h:form id="myForm">
             <rich:collapsiblePanel id="myPanel" header="Header" switchType="client">
              <h:outputText value="Test" />
             </rich:collapsiblePanel>
            </h:form>
```

In Google Chrome (tested with Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)) we've noticed a strange javascript error after page load. This error occurs randomly but not always:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItems' of undefined
at init (togglePanelItem.js:43)
at new init (collapsiblePanelItem.js:32)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (collapsiblePanel.js:52)
at fire (jquery.js?amp;v=4.5.13.Final:3232)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?amp;v=4.5.13.Final:3362)
at Function.ready (jquery.js?amp;v=4.5.13.Final:3582)
at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js?amp;v=4.5.13.Final:3617)
```

For example, if I'm reloading the page 10 times this error will occurs around 5 times. In other browsers like Firefox this error never occurs.

It looks like that the javascript files are randomly loadad. So I'm already tried to use compressed files for RichFaces by setting the `org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled` to true but the error still occurs.

I would like to solve this issue, but I have no idea how can I localise this issue.

**EDIT**

After debugging a while, I found out that there are some parallels to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13780 because sometimes `element[rf.RICH_CONTAINER]` is undefined in `rf.component` for some reasons.

Comment: Well, you can debug the JavaScript. That said I don't see why this wouldn't work, the error indicates that the parent element wasn't found but that shouldn't be happening. You can try upgrading to the latest version of RichFaces but I don't think any relevant code changes happened.

Comment: With the latest RichFaces version 4.5.17.Final I'm still having the same problem. After debugging, I found out that element[rf.RICH_CONTAINER] of the CollapsiblePanel is sometimes undefined.

Comment: Looks like a bug then, unfortunately not much you can do, unless you want to fix it yourself.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue with Chrome 56 or earlier?

Comment: @Makhiel for me it looks like chrome script engine works in different way now.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue?

Comment: I don't know if we had this issue with an older version of Chrome but it occurs only during the last time. Is there any way to get a old version of Chrome?

Comment: We've solved our problem by creating a simple composite component which has similar functions.