# JS error on Chrome 57+ for RichFaces application "Cannot read property 'switchToItem' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, jsp, richfaces

I've a jsp page with tabs. and sometimes an error occurs (when I press a tab) "Cannot read property 'switchToItem' of undefined"
[image: undefined error]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchToItem' of undefined 
at init.__onHeaderClick (packed.js:6102)
at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (packed.js:1333)
at HTMLTableCellElement.dispatch (jquery.js:846)
at HTMLTableCellElement.eventHandle (jquery.js:722)
```

as I understand the error happens in packed.js (this is a js-file packed by richfaces of version 4.3.4). I've looked inside this file and found that RichFaces try to find a list of tabs. these tabs are located in property "rf" (`element[richfaces.RICH_CONTAINER]`), but in moment when I pressed a tab, there was no property.

This bug reproduce in chrome v.57, in version 56 it doesn't reproduce.
Could you help me with some advice, how it can be fixed?

some technical details:

- I use `xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"` `<rich:tabPanel>` tag in my jsp page
- in pom.xml `<richfaces.version>4.3.4.Final</richfaces.version>`

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest version of RichFaces first.

Comment: It still reproducible with RichFaces 4.3.7

Comment: The last is 4.5.17 and there won't be any others. This is probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926712/

Comment: Has anyone found a workaround for this? We are having the same issue with RF 4.3 and Chrome 57. Upgrading to RF 4.5 is not possible (requires JSF 2.2 if I remember correctly) and apparently it doesn't work with 4.5 either

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have the reputation points to make this a comment.

I don't know if google chrome knows about this problem or would be willing to fix it. Our response to this is to patch RichFaces 4.3.7.Final javascript to not use the adhoc dom element property but a global map instead and then deploy our own richfaces jar to our production environment at the end of the month (after testing). I don't have to ability to deploy this to central repo but if you wanted to see the direct changes I made you can see my commits (https://github.com/JamieGHamilton/core). If chrome fixes the problem then this won't be an issue but I'm not counting on that.
So far the changes I made work perfectly in chrome (and other browsers)

Update: I've included the fix found by dennyDarko - thanks for this. My understanding is that the Chrome 58-beta doesn't produce this behavior so for some affected apps, the admins may choose to wait.

Comment: Hi @James-G could you eleborate on what causes this issue in Google Chrome v.57? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

James G, you have a mistake in richfaces.js

```
   richfaces.$$ = function(componentName, element) {
        while (element.parentNode) {
            var containerId = element.getAttribute(richfaces.RICH_CONTAINER);
            if (containerId && containerId !== "" && !!richfaces.COMPONENT_MAP[containerId] && richfaces.COMPONENT_MAP[containerId].component.name == componentName) {
                return e.component;
            }
            else {
                element = element.parentNode;
            }
        }
};
```

There is no `e`. You need change it to

```
...
return richfaces.COMPONENT_MAP[containerId].component;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This might he an issue of Chrome 57. Try Chrome 58 Beta.

Comment: The issue is not reproduced with Chrome 58

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Richfaces 4.5.17.Final and Chrome 92.
Additionally there was the following log message:

```
<jsf.non_displayed_message> <WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(One or more resources have the target of 'body', but no 'body' component has been defined within the view.), detail=(One or more resources have the target of 'body', but no 'body' component has been defined within the view.)]>
```

So changing **body** to **h:body** in the main XHTML file has resolved the issue.
And **h:head** contains <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces"/>